# Unable to Import File using h2o in Python

Tags: python, import, h2o

I'm trying to import a file using h2o in Python.

h2o.init() is successful, but when I do the following:

***df = h2o.import_file(path = "Combined Database - Final.csv")***

I get a number of errors that I can't find any help on. Here is the last one that shows up:

> H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error:
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=54321): Max retries exceeded
>   with url: /3/Jobs/
>   $03017f00000132d4ffffffff$_a6edaa906ba7a556a417c13149c940db (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
>   10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/netw ork
>   address/port) is normally permitted',))

Above it, there are “OSError”, “NewConnectionError”, “MaxRetryError”.

This is my first time using h2o, and I can't even import my data. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: please include a complete code snippet, include the code you used to start h2o, include what version of h2o you are using. And please verify that h2o is not already running somewhere else.

Comment: import sys  
import h2o   
h2o.remove_all()  
h2o.init()  
from h2o.estimators.random_forest import H2ORandomForestEstimator  
df = h2o.import_file(path = "Combined Database - Final.csv")

Comment: and i just downloaded h2o today, so it's the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

please see the user guide: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/starting-h2o.html

please also run the following tests (reposted from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/vMzJ0dvV2Ko)) to debug your issue.

1. Does running h2o.jar from the commandline work? 
   And if so, does h2o.init() then connect to it?
2. What do the logs say?
3. Disable your firewall, and see if it makes a difference. (Remember to 
   re-enable it afterwards).
4. Try a different port number (the default is 54321).
5. Shutdown h2o (h2o.shutdown()) and try running h2o.init() and see if it works.

Comment: hi @pixiesweet44 the easiest way to get help is to update your question with explicit steps of what you did and what errors you got as you try new things out. It's hard to know what went wrong if you simply post "h2o.jar does not work".  For example I don't know if you followed the instructions from the downloads page http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wright/6/index.html or did something else. I also don't know how you were able to run h2o.remove_all() before running h2o.init(). Poke around a bit more through the documentation, I think you'll be able to figure it out. best of luck!